# cannot use a static function in a static field declaration

Tags: php, static-methods, static-members

I have a static field in a class with a regex. This regex requires a list of values that are in a static array, so I create a static function that returns the group (e.g. `(a|b|c|d)`) to be inserted in the regex. Problem is that I can't call a static function when I declare a static field.

I would need to put the value returned by the function inside the field.

Example:

```
class A {
    public static function Foo()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }

    public static $Bar = "lol". self::Foo();
}

echo A::$Bar;
```

I get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' on line 7
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Why you use `self::Foo()` ? instead `Foo()`

Comment: that ain't possible in PHP, when setting properties, they need to be simple declarations. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php. its stated in the first paragraph

Comment: You can't, you use `echo A::$Foo();` instead

Comment: The workround is to use `echo A::$Foo();` instead, as I already said

Comment: The result of Foo() is just a part of the string which is in Bar,  I will edit the question

Comment: @Phate01 You can't assign expressions to static properties also there is no workaround. Why not use normal properties and methods ?

Comment: The class is supposed to be static. I'll find another way, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize a static property with "dynamic" values. You can only initialize it with a literal or a constant.

You can also see this in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, **static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed**. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

If you want to use the static function just use it like this:

```
echo A::Foo();
```

Comment: @Phate01 No, you can't assign the static method to the property. (Just added how you use your static method)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to do something in a way that the language doesn't permit, reverse your thinking and do it in a way that the language will allow:

```
class A {
    public static function Foo()
    {
        return "lol" . self::$Bar;
    }

    public static $Bar = "Foo";
}

echo A::Foo();
```